# How should the invisble objects of my code relate to their visible widget counterparts?

Tags: python, user-interface, coding-style, qt4

When programming a GUI (usually with Python and PyQt4), I try to organise my code neatly and I often face the same question:

**How should the invisible objects (data) of my code relate to their visible widget counterparts (graphic representation)?**

For instance, suppose I have a list of entries from a linguistic dictionary. Each entry is an abstract data object with various attributes and functions. Each entry also is represented graphically as a widget the user can interact with.

I believe there are four possible ways of organising them:

1. the widget object is a child of the data object;
2. the data object is a child of the widget object;
3. the widget object and the data item are merged into one object (data are attributes of the widget);
4. the widget object and the data object exist separately and the latter is fed into the former (e.g. as *args)

Now I am not sure whether or not there is some conventional agreement regarding this and I am not certain either whether these possible arrangements really make a difference.

What is the best practice?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here.  What are these "abstract objects" you're talking about?  Variables?  Class Attributes?  Globals?  With no code here there's no good way to answer this IMO.

Comment: OK, let me try to give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Python or QT, but it sounds like you're looking for an organization called:

[Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

The idea is, that your Data Object (Model) can live far away from your Widget (View). They are coordinated by a Controller.

This is extremely prevalent in Objective-C / Cocoa, and to a lesser extent, Android.

Most modern web frameworks are also based on this concept, as well.

**EDIT:** At least to some degree, QT does as well:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq10-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks. What would you suggest is the "controller" in the example I give? (Because as I see it, I have only a data and its view, and the data is interacted with through the view i.e. the widget).

Comment: The controller is the part of the program that (among other things) figures out which data items should be displayed and passes them to the view. The view then renders them as widgets. It doesn't know anything about any program logic other than that.